# Difference between the vector that spans the kernel of a matrix vs basis of the kernel of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a difference between the vector that spans the kernel of a matrix vs basis of the kernel of a matrix? I feel like I might be missing something conceptual.

Comment: A basis is a **linearly independent** vector that spans the kernel of a matrix. A general vector that spans the kernel may or may not be linearly independent

Comment: A vector is a vector, a basis is a set of vectors.

Comment: @Sauhard, how can a vector fail to be linearly independent (unless it's the zero vector)?

Comment: @GerryMyerson My mistake. I meant vector as in the set of vectors that span the kernel. I mistakenly used the wrong terminology

Comment: In case a given subspace is one dimensional, any nonzero vector therein forms a (singleton) basis of it.